# Applying a Function to Null in Javascript

Tags: javascript, call

Why does the following work:

```
function sum(a,b) { return a + b; }
var result = sum.call(null,3,4);     // 7
```

Why is result defined? I am invoking sum as a method of null. But null is not an object and cannot have properties!

What is going on?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The first argument for `Function.prototype.call` is the *context*, which defines the `this` value for the execution context of the invoked function, nothing else.

So basically, you're saying that `this` is referring to `null` (at least, in ES5 strict mode), but since you don't access `this` anyway, it makes no difference.

In non-strict mode, `this` cannot be `null`, so it's replaced with the *global object* instead.

Comment: `this` is not [context](http://es5.github.com/#x10-toc), it's a component of an execution context.

Comment: @RobG: its probably misleading the way I described it. However, `this` will *refer* to the context/scope object for the current execution context.

Comment: jAndy—it's impossible to reference a scope object (other than the limited facility provided by *with* and the special case of a global object), it's expressly forbbiden by ECMA-262 (See [§10.2 Lexical Environments](http://es5.github.com/#x10.2), last sentence). And `this` is one parameter that is set as a component of an execution context (see [§10.3 Execution Contexts](http://es5.github.com/#x10.3)), where it also says it is impossible to access an execution context.

Comment: @RobG: oh come one man, I now about this language and I don't need to read all those links again. Whats wrong with you ? I'm not talking about the specification and implementation of "scope" and context objects. It should be pretty obvious what I mean with "context" here.

Comment: however, I don't want to induce a flamewar here. I guess you just want to be a little picky, thats just fine. But you and everybody who reads this should be able to identify what I'm talking about, and that is ecmascript-objects which are referred by `this`. Its pretty pretty common to call that "context", even if the spec has of course a different meaning of that.

Answer (score 12):

When you use `.call` or `.apply` with `null` or `undefined`, the default `this` (usually `window`) is automatically used instead if not in strict mode.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) (emphasis mine):

> `thisArg`
>   The value of `this` provided for the call to `fun`. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: **if the method is a function in non-strict mode code, `null` and `undefined` will be replaced with the global object**, and primitive values will be boxed.

If you *are* in strict mode, it actually will be `null` or `undefined`.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    return this;
}).call(null); // null
```

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    return this;
})(); // undefined
```

Comment: I dont think you quoted MDN correctly, look at Alfabravo's answer.

Comment: @Fawkes5: Maybe if you don't think I quoted MDN correctly, you should follow the link to MDN I provided and see for yourself that it's exactly the same? The only differences between Alfabravo's answer and mine are "fun" (the original text) and the emphasis (which I already said was mine).

Comment: i know but what's with the thisArg, and 'fun' in the first sentence

Comment: @Fawkes5: `fun` is the name of the function. `thisArg` is the name of the first argument to `.call`. (Again - see the documentation.)

Comment: :Ah i see. Regardless its out of context.

Answer (score 4):

Its not. NULL in this case specifies to what object the `this` keyword is bound to. In your method, by setting it to NULL it will either not have a `this` variable binding or it will be bound to the function itself or the window.

Since you're not using any variables or functions that are accessed via `this`, then there's no need to use the call method ... you can just use `sum(3,4)`

Answer (score 1):

As stated in, for example, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), the first argument is

> The value of this provided for the call to [the method].  Note that
>   this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is
>   a function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be
>   replaced with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed.

Answer (score -1):

As the MDN explained.

> thisArg
>
> The value of this provided for the call to fun. Note that this may not
>   be the actual value seen by  the method: if the method is a function
>   in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced  with the
>   global object, and primitive values will be boxed.

Simply put it by a little code.

```
<script >
        'use strict'
        function fun() {
            alert(this);
        }
        fun.call(null);

    </script>
```

In the strict mode ,this is null. But in the not strict mode . this is window or global object.