# JavaScript: get to arguments object of callback

Tags: javascript

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/679we0Lx/)

I'm looking at making some very high level logic into helper functions for curiosity's sake.  I would like to be able to execute a function with its parameters in the `_if` function without having to define something like `_callback` ahead of time?  I feel like I'm missing something here.

```
var _if = function(predicate,callback){
    if(predicate){
        callback(); //callback(arguments) is not arguments for callback
    }
};
var text = 'some text';
_if(1 > 0,function(){
    console.log('hello world'); //hello world
});
_if(1 > 0,function(text){
    console.log(text); //undefined
});
//define callback for this situation
var _callback = function(x){
    console.log(x);
}
_if(1 > 0,function(){
    _callback(text); //some text
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you want, but maybe this helps:

You can call your function like this too:

```
_if(1 > 0,_callback.bind(null,text));  //null is the value of this

_if(1,function(text){
    console.log(text); //this way not undefined
}.bind(null,text));
```

1) This works because of the [logic](http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.5) of JavaScript. In further versions you can use your version too if you use `let text = 'some text';` - [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

2) `null` is the this value for the function, (more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)) but I think you can pass `this` too if you need to use it in the function (`null` will be automatically replaced in non-strict mode to the global object. That's why you can use `window.colsole.log` inside the function. - [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11659134/669677))

Comment: i'm looking for a way to get at the arguments object of the callback function in the `_if` function, without having to define _callback beforehand.  In the second call to _if you can really see what i'm trying to get at.  that function prints undefined when i pass in parameters to the callback.

Comment: thanks, that's what i was looking for.  two questions: 1.) why does this work, 2.) why pass null instead of `this`? as the context?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just take the arguments to the callback function as extra parameters on `_if`?

```
var _if = function (predicate, callback, context) {
    if (predicate) {
        var callbackArgs = [].slice.call(arguments, 3);
        callback.apply(context || null, callbackArgs);
    }
};

// Usage:
_if(true, console.log, console, "text");
```

Comment: because i knew that way would work and i was looking for reasons why i hadn't seen what i asked about :)

Comment: why pass null at the context to apply?

Comment: You didn't specify you wanted a calling context as well. You could easily have a 3rd named argument for the context and change the `slice` argument to 3, and that would work. With some clever thinking about your argument list, you could probably even find a way to require only one function (which can deduce if a calling context was passed in or not).

Comment: Oops, never mind, now I see. It wasn't clear that your question was specifically about `this`. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: i think i actually like this better than what i was going after.  it reads nicely to have the parameters meant for the callback passed last.