# How to set null context in call function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function test(){         
     if(this === null){
        console.log("This is null");
     }else{
         console.log("This is Object");
     }
 }
test.call(null);
test.call({});
```

Output :

> This is Object.
>
> This is Object.

But I expect Output :

> This is Null.
>
> This is Object.

Why Null not set in context ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying a Function to Null in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659134/applying-a-function-to-null-in-javascript)

Comment: @Mr.Developer It doesn't seem to be similar. The function in that question doesn't use `this` at all, he just wondered why `null` was allowed in `.call()`.

Comment: @ObethSamuel: What do you feel is not credible/official about MDN, from which Tushar's existing answer is drawn?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

> if the method is a function in non-strict mode, `null` and `undefined` will be replaced with the global object and primitive values will be converted to objects.

This explains why you get an object when you call `test.call(null);`. When `null` is passed here, `this` inside `test()` will be global object `Window`.

For the desired behavior, use strict mode.

```js
function test() {
  "use strict";
  if (this === null) {
    console.log("This is null");
  } else {
    console.log("This is Object");
  }
}
test.call(null);
test.call({});
```

Quoting from ES6 Specifications for [strict mode](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-of-ecmascript)

> If `this` is evaluated within strict mode code, then the `this` value is not coerced to an object. A `this` value of `null` or `undefined` is not converted to the global object and primitive values are not converted to wrapper objects. The `this` value passed via a function call (including calls made using `Function.prototype.apply` and `Function.prototype.call`) do not coerce the passed this value to an object

Answer (score 4):

What does the 'this' indicate? you can use `console.log(this);` to know it. But as answer, use an input (here I called it `input`) and test it.

```js
   function test(input){
 if(input=== null){
    console.log("This is null");
 }else{
     console.log("This is Object");
 }
 }
test(null);
test({});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://es5.github.io/#x15.3.4.4

> NOTE The thisArg value is passed without modification as the this
>   value. This is a change from Edition 3, where a undefined or null
>   thisArg is replaced with the global object and ToObject is applied to
>   all other values and that result is passed as the this value.

In your case you are not in strict mode, if you set strict mode `this` can be set to anything you want. Be careful though, you can end up referencing things you do not want to by accident.

```js
//global object being set, since this can't be null
function test(){         
     if(this === null){
        console.log("This is null");
     }else{
         console.log("This is Object");
     }
 }
test.call(null);
test.call({});

//example of strict returning null
function test2(){  
"use strict";
     if(this === null){
        console.log("This is null");
     }else{
         console.log("This is Object");
     }
 }
test2.call(null);
test2.call({});
```

Answer (score 0):

As ***@Tushar*** mentioned in his answer:

> `this` inside `test()` will be global object **`Window`**

.

On the other hand, your function has not argument and as ***@Elnaz*** mentioned in her answer you can add an argument to it to get the null from caller inside the function and I want add this note:

> Also you can get `null` value in the output in a function without
>   parameter by `arguments[0]` when you call your function with
>   `test(null)`

```js
function test(){  
     input=arguments[0];       
     if(input === null){
        console.log("This is null");
     }else{
         console.log("This is Object");
     }
 }
test(null);
test({});
```

Or with `arguments[1]` when you call it by `test.call(this,null)`:

```js
function test(){  
     input=arguments[0];       
     if(input === null){
        console.log("This is null");
     }else{
         console.log("This is Object");
     }
 }
test.call(this,null);
test.call(this,{});
```