# Passing `null` as context object vs directly calling the function

Tags: javascript

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659134), given that I don't want to specify any context, hence, passing `null` to `thisArg` in `call()`.

What would be the difference between line 2 and line 3 in the following code? Is there any benefit from doing one over the other?

```js
function sum(a,b) { return a + b; }
var result1 = sum.call(null,3,4);     // 7
var result2 = sum(3,4);               // 7
```

Similarly for `apply()`:

```js
var arr = [1,2,4];
var result3 = Math.max.apply(null, arr);   // 4
var result4 = Math.max(...arr);            // 4
```

Comment: If you don't specify a context, it defaults to the global object (`window` in browsers).

Comment: `call` only makes sense if you’re using `this` in the function. `apply` only has a benefit over `call` if you’re in an environment that doesn’t support ES6.

Comment: @Barmar  Except in strict mode functions.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder And now I've learned that in non-strict, `null` gets turned into the global object, so they're really equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on whether the function you're calling was defined in loose mode or [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

When calling a loose-mode function, the following three things all call the function such that `this` within the call is the global object for the environment (`globalThis`, aka `window` on browsers):

- Calling the function without setting `this`: `fn()`
- Calling the function providing a `this` value of `undefined`: `fn.call(undefined)` and similar
- Calling the function providing a `this` value of `null`: `fn.call(null)` and similar

With a strict mode function, the first two both cause `this` during the call to be `undefined`, and the third (explicitly setting it to `null`) sets it to (you guessed it) `null`.

Examples:

```js
function loose() {
    console.log(`loose: ${this === null ? "null" : typeof this}`);
}

loose();
loose.call(undefined);
loose.call(null);

function strict() {
    "use strict";
    console.log(`strict: ${this === null ? "null" : typeof this}`);
}

strict();
strict.call(undefined);
strict.call(null);
```

In the normal case, if you don't need to set `this` to anything in particular, just call the function so the default behavior takes place.

- One wrinkle: If you have an array of arguments you need to spread out as discrete arguments to the function, in any even vaguely up-to-date environment, you can use spread notation to do that: `fn(...theArray)`. If you're stuck in an obsolete environment, the rough equivalent is `fn.apply(undefined, theArray)`.

If you have a specific need to set a specific `this` value, you can do that via `call` or `apply` (as you've found), including (for strict mode functions) `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: @AcaNg - Gah! You're right. :-) Thanks, I've fixed it. Glad that helped!

Answer (score 2):

TJ Crowder has the detailed response here, but as a general rule:

- `fn.call(null)`: In almost all cases, just call the function.
- `fn.apply(null, args)`: This is useful in some cases where you have an array of arguments and your environment doesn't support `...args`, but otherwise spreading the arguments is probably more conventional: `fn(...args)`

Comment: Thank you. `...args` is only supported in ES2015. I will note this to myself. "In almost all cases, just call the function." So I suppose there are _almost_ no difference here. But what about the other cases ?

Comment: See @TJCrowder's answer above. There are cases where you are in strict mode and use `this` in the body of the function, and the value of `this` will be different. But that would only make sense for relatively esoteric use cases where you have statements like `if (this) { ... }`